# I am using EJS to display queried data from mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

ReferenceError: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\club ape\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\views\index.ejs:255
253|
254|

> > 255|                         <% for (let member of members){ %>
> > 256|                         
> > 257|                             " alt="..." />
> > 258|
> >
> > ##### <%= member.Name %>

//my ejs code

```
                   <% for (let member of members){ %>
                    <div class="team-member">
                        <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="/uploads/<%= member.img %>" alt="..." />
                        <h4> <%= member.Name %> </h4>
                        <p class="text-muted"><%= member.Fonction %></p>
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="#!" aria-label="Parveen Anand Twitter Profile"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="#!" aria-label="Parveen Anand Facebook Profile"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="#!" aria-label="Parveen Anand LinkedIn Profile"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% } %>
```

Comment: share js code (where you passed member value)

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var schemaMember = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:String,
    Name:String,
    Fonction:String,
    img:String

})

var member = mongoose.model('member',schemaMember)
var url='mongodb://localhost:27017/ape/member'
exports.getallmembers=()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    mongoose.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true}).then(()=>{
        return members.find({})
    })
    
    }).then(members=>{
        mongoose.disconnect()
        resolve(members)
    }).catch(err=>reject(err))
}

Comment: did you pass members while rendering index.ejs?